# HTML Canvas help for touchscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, touch

Hi there Im working on a mobile specific website that involves the users drawing shapes and patterns on their mobile. 
Im having trouble implementing this for mobile The canvas drawing workings perfectly with desktop but not at all with touchscreen devices. 
Ive triedn using touch events but they dont seem to be working at all. Below is my code. Any help would be much appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>


<style>
canvas { border: 5px solid blue }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>


<script>
function midPointBtw(p1, p2) {
  return {
    x: p1.x + (p2.x - p1.x) / 2,
    y: p1.y + (p2.y - p1.y) / 2
  };
 }

function getPattern() {
  return ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
 }


var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 50;
ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';

var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = getPattern();
};
img.src = "dick2.png";

var isDrawing, points = [ ];

el.ontouchstart = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });

};

el.ontouchmove = function(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;

  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  var p1 = points[0];
  var p2 = points[1];

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);

  for (var i = 1, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
    var midPoint = midPointBtw(p1, p2);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(p1.x, p1.y, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
    p1 = points[i];
    p2 = points[i+1];
  }
  ctx.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
  ctx.stroke();
};

el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
  points.length = 0;
};




function showInput() {
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("user_input").value;
    }







</script>


<form id ="search">
<input type = "text" name="message" id="user_input">
<input type = "button" value= "Submit" onclick="showInput();">
</form>



<p><span id='display'></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Touch events work differently compared to mouse events. Instead of just `clientX` and `clientY` being on the event itself, due to touchscreens being able to support multiple touch points at various sensitivities, they are accessible in a different location, under [`touches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/touches). If you only care about the first touch in the list, you can make your code compatible with both desktop and mobile fairly easily with minimal changes:

```js
function midPointBtw(p1, p2) {
  return {
    x: p1.x + (p2.x - p1.x) / 2,
    y: p1.y + (p2.y - p1.y) / 2
  };
}

function getPattern() {
  return ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
}


var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 50;
ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';

var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = getPattern();
};
img.src = "https://placekitten.com/200";

var isDrawing, points = [];

var getXY = function(e) {
  var source = e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;

  return {
    x: source.clientX,
    y: source.clientY
  };
};

var startDrawing = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  points.push(getXY(e));
};
var keepDrawing = function(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;

  points.push(getXY(e));
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  var p1 = points[0];
  var p2 = points[1];

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);

  for (var i = 1, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
    var midPoint = midPointBtw(p1, p2);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(p1.x, p1.y, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
    p1 = points[i];
    p2 = points[i + 1];
  }
  ctx.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
  ctx.stroke();
};
var stopDrawing = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
  points = [];
};

el.addEventListener('touchstart', startDrawing);
el.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrawing);

el.addEventListener('touchmove', keepDrawing);
el.addEventListener('mousemove', keepDrawing);

el.addEventListener('touchend', stopDrawing);
el.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrawing);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 5px solid blue
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks man appreciate the help, I just have a few more questions. Im having issues with connecting my original image with my mobile device, But when I tried your code with the place holder image it worked perfectly. Is there anywhere online I could upload images as placeholders? (like the one you have of the kitten) and just input the link into my code? in so I can use those images as my drawing strokes, this just seems easier. Thanks

Comment: Also,When I draw on the canvas its just one continuous stroke. is it possible to have it in a way that you draw then stop then draw again and so on. I.E. just draw multiple times not just one continuous stroke?

Comment: I would suggest that you ask these as a separate question, after looking around and seeing if there's not a question covering this already.